# JQuery formatting syntax for header (CSS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to format the title bar of a custom jQuery UI dialog box. The dialog box has a specified class (e.g. `.orange`) as follows:

```
.ui-dialog.orange {
    background: #F9F9F9;
    border: 3px solid orange;
}
```

I want to change the title bar as follows

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar {
    background: purple;
}
```

But only for the class `.orange`

I tried

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar.orange {
    background: purple;
}
```

and

```
.ui-dialog.orange {
     background: #F9F9F9;
     border: 3px solid orange;
     #titlebar {
         background: purple;
     }
 }
```

Without any success. Could anyone provide me with right syntax, please? Thanks.

Comment: Try posting the emitted html of the entire dialog

Comment: So you use sass or less? because of the nested `#titlebar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is selecting **nested** element(s).

```
 .ui-dialog.orange .ui-dialog-titlebar {
   background: purple;
 }
```

Or, if you use preprocessor (SASS/LESS):

```
.ui-dialog {
   /* ... */
   &.orange {
     .ui-dialog-titlebar {
       background: purple;
     }
   }
 }
```